# Permissions on Document App within Document Center

Tags: 2013, permissions

I'm in the process of setting up a SharePoint 2013 test environment for work. We've got a structure as follows. Names have been made generic

http://sharepoint/ - which goes to a top level, group directory which lists each company.
http://sharepoint/sites/Company1 - which goes to company1's SharePoint page. This is a new site collection, part of the same Web Application but NOT a subsite of http://sharepoint/
http://sharepoint/sites/company1/documentcenter/ - This is the document center part of the company's sharepoint, which IS a subsite of company1 sharepoint.

Within the http://sharepoint/sites/company1/documentcenter there is a Web App, of the Documents app which is on the home page, so users can view the items in there and if they want to go into folders, they'll click the link of the Web App, which is http://sharepoint/sites/company1/documentcenter/documents

Hope that makes sense so far!

Permissions time. I've turned **off** inheritance of permissions for the DocumentCenter subsite from the main company1 subsite as we want some users to access document center but not all. On the DocumentCenter subsite I've created a permission level called Company Document Center Viewers, which has the following rights:

- View Items
- Open Items
- Create Alerts
- Browse Directories
- View Pages
- Browse User Information
- Use Remote Interfaces (required for when we use Office Web Apps)
- Use Client Integration Features
- Open
- Edit Personal User Information

I've then created a group called Company Document Center Viewers and assigned it that permission level. 
Within AD, I've created a security group called Company Document Center Viewers and added a user to that AD security group.

When browsing as the user, I can browse to http://sharepoint/sites/company1/documentcenter
I can't browse to http://sharepoint/sites/company1 - this is intentional

However, when in the Document Center subsite and I try to open the Documents Web App (url of http://sharepoint/sites/company1/documentcenter/documents/forms/allitems.aspx) I get an error message saying this site hasn't been shared with me.

Back logged in as admin, I check and the list inherits permissions from the Document Center subsite.

My question is why isn't it working and letting my test user view the list so they can then navigate folders easier?

Hope it all makes sense!

Thanks guys. This site has been a huge help with getting me into SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, probably a stupid question! Figured it out myself.

Needed to add the permission level of "View Application pages- View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists."